# Optimum parameters for audio slicing using FFMpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, perl

I am planning to use Perl to extract audio from media files through FFMpeg. Now as far as I know, FFMpeg needs lot of parameters like bit-rate, etc which it used to extract the audio. So for one particular video, we may supply the params through testing, and FFMpeg will give us the audio. But when I need to apply it to lots of media files, I need some optimum params which will always extract decent audio from all.

So can anyone guide me what should be the default params I must use to ensure that almost all media files give decent audio extraction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `-codec copy` or `-c copy` (or `-c:a copy`). This will copy the bit stream 100%. Copying the bit stream has certain limitations, in that you can only cut on key frames; but as far as I'm aware, that mostly applies to video streams rather than audio (audio codecs don't have an analogue to key frames as far as I know). Personally, I've never come across any problems cutting up audio with bit stream copying.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c:a copy -ss 10 -t 50 output.mp3
```

Your next-best option would be to use uncompressed PCM audio (`-c:a pcm_s16le`) or a lossless codec like FLAC (`-c:a flac`). These will produce identical-sounding audio to the original. This will give you a larger file, though.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c:a pcm_s16le -ss 10 -t 50 output.wav
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c:a flac -ss 10 -t 50 output.flac
```

You can put `-ss` before the input to speed things up considerably, though this may give less accurate seeking. Since you're scripting this, you might find some use for the `-to` option (see the [documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html)).

Comment: Can you give me the complete command regarding the `-c:a flac`?

Comment: Yeah, when I am using `-vcodec copy -acodec copy`, often the slice comes out to be longer than the duration specified. A 5 second slice yields 15 seconds duration. This is I guess due to the ky frame factor, since it can't slice the key frame mid-way, it goes ahead until that frame is finished. Right?

Comment: @Cupidvogel yes, that sounds like a keyframe issue; *if* you're working with *just* audio, then (based on my own experience) you won't have any problems - but I haven't tested that with an exhaustive list of inputs.

Comment: @Cupidvogel A key frame does not last for several seconds. The interval between key frames is what counts (the [length of the Group of Pictures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_pictures). Exact cutting is, as evilsoup said, not always possible though – that's correct.